# e.preventDefault() does not work. AJAX / Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5.4

I have an Ajax call which sends user form input to be processed in the back end. The controller in the back-end sends back result as JSON, when the form is submitted the page reloads and redirects to a blank page with raw JSON instead of the json being picked up by AJAX.

This is the Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').on('submit', '#topup-form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $('form').attr('action'),
                method: 'post',
                data: $('form').serialize(),

                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                },

                error: function(errorData){
                    alert(errorData);
                }
            });
        });
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

This is the Laravel controller, if the validation fails it sends Json, if the user is authenticated, it redirects the user, else it returns 401 asking user to login.

```
public function topupPost(Request $request) {
    $validator = [
    'topupAmount'=> 'required|integer|between:10,500',
    'phonenumber'=> 'required|regex:/^05[602][0-9]{7}$/',
    ];

    $inputs = $request->all();

    Log::info($inputs);

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $validator);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $validator->messages(),
            'code' => 400
        ], 400);
    }

    elseif (Auth::check()) {
         return view('pages.checkout', compact('inputs')); 
     }

     return Response::json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => "Please login first",
            'code' => 401
        ], 401);    
}
```

What happens is that nothing pops up as an alert but the user is redirected to a page with the raw JSON.

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end

Comment: Are you sure that you are listening to the right event? If I'm not mistaken, that is searching for an element with id 'topup-form' inside every '<form>' element

Comment: @Justinas i added onsubmit="return false" and it worked. thank you.

Comment: @Gerard there's only form with that id, but I also rewrote the call to be like this: $('#topup-form').submit(function(e){... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue 
I solved it by changing the submit button type to "button" so that the form does not auto submit. my ajax code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $("#submit").click(function() {   
            var loginForm = $("#contactForm");
            var formData = loginForm.serialize();

              /*alert(formData);*/

                 $.ajax({
                     url: /*you URL*/,
                     type:'post',
                     data:formData,
                     success:function(data){
                         //alert(data);     //for redirecting instead of alert try below code

                         if(data == "") {       //True Case i.e. passed validation
                          alert('error')
                         }
                         else {                 //False Case: With error msg
                         alert(data);   //$msg is the id of empty msg
                         }

                     },
                     error: function (data) {
                         /*console.log(data);*/
                         alert(data);
                     }
                 });

           });

         /*alert('Successfully Loaded');*/

         });
```

also your php response handle seems fine. hope this helps